# Postgresql check if exists listen/notify function with specific name

Tags: postgresql

In one of DB migrations there are next commands:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION notify_document_package_update() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
    BEGIN
    PERFORM pg_notify('document_package_update','');
    RETURN NULL;
    END;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trigger_document_package_update ON invoices;
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_document_package_update
  AFTER UPDATE OR DELETE OR INSERT OR TRUNCATE
  ON invoices
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE notify_document_package_update();
```

Now I want to ensure that `notify_document_package_update()` exist in the database. (Insure that all fine on test/stage db).

How to do it with SQL query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done with next query:

```
SELECT routine_name FROM information_schema.routines where routine_name='notify_document_package_update';
```